# Getting dates to stop on Friday on JavaScript function

Tags: javascript

How do I get my code to only show dates up until Friday, it currently shows dates until Saturday:

```js
var dayString = ["Sunday", "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday"];

var now = new Date();
var currentDay = now.getDay(); // return 0 for Sunday, 6 for Saturday
var result = [];
var tempDate = new Date(now.getTime());
tempDate.setDate(now.getDate() - (currentDay + 6) % 7); // now tempDate is previous Monday
while (tempDate.getDay() != 0) {
  var currentMonth = tempDate.getMonth() + 1;
  if (currentMonth < 10) currentMonth = "0" + currentMonth;
  result.push([tempDate.getDay() - 1, tempDate.getDate() + "-" + currentMonth + "-" + tempDate.getFullYear(), dayString[tempDate.getDay()]]);
  tempDate.setDate(tempDate.getDate() + 1);
}
console.log(result);
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xut9tkpz/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get dates until next friday use this:

```
var now = new Date();
var results = [];
while(now.getDay() !== 5) {
 results.push(new Date(now)); // push Date Object to results;
 now.setDate(now.getDate() + 1);
}
```

if you want to get dates until last friday:

```
var now = new Date();
var results = [];
while(now.getDay() !== 5) {
 results.push(new Date(now)); // push Date Object to results;
 now.setDate(now.getDate() - 1);
}
```

if you want to get dates until last friday from 1 week into the past:

```
var now = new Date();
now.setDate(now.getDate() - 7);
var results = [];
while(now.getDay() !== 5) {
 results.push(new Date(now)); // push Date Object to results;
 now.setDate(now.getDate() + 1);
}
```

if you want to include friday into the results objects just change the `5` to `6`

Comment: Answers should include why the OP has their issue and how your code fixes it. Code–only answers aren't that helpful.

Answer (score 1):

In ECMAScript, day numbers are 0 for Sunday, 1 for Monday through to 6 for Saturday.

The part:

```
while (tempDate.getDay() != 0)
```

means "keep going until Sunday", so it stops the day before, i.e. Saturday. Just change to:

```
while (tempDate.getDay() != 6)
```

so it stops on Friday.